# Fontenc T1 changes underscores

Tags: font-encodings, scrartcl

When using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to get correct umlauts, underscores are displayed much wider and subscript than without it and backslashes are much more angled and taller. Is there a way to revert this while still keeping correct umlaut output?
The document uses the class scrartcl.

Comment: with T1 you get the underscore from the font as chosen by the font designer with OT1 you get the default which is a drawn rule `\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textunderscore}{\leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule\@width.3em}}
`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the command that you proposed did not change that behaviour though.

Comment: oh no I was just showing the original definition so it is only used for encodings that don't have `_` I guess you want `\renewcommand\_{\leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule width.3em}}`

Comment: thanks a lot, I misunderstood you there. The command you provided works great in the "normal" document-body, but it seems to get ignored in my bibliography (biblatex with biber-backend and style=authortitle, if that's relevant). Do you know why?

Comment: OT1 does not have a backslash so in OT1 you get `$\backslash$`  rather than the `\ ` from the current font.

Comment: your bibtex style must redefine it again, but without an example don't propose to guess. incidentally "breaks" in the title is not the word I'd use for "use the character the font designer intended" :-) is biblatex writing `\_` or is it writing the literal character `_` in which case you would get the `_` from the font, usually.

Comment: I changed the posts title. I think biblatex write the literal underscore character.

Comment: so it's a bit harder (are you sure you want this:-) but something like ``\catcode`\_=13 \def_{\_}``  but just locally near the bibliography as it will break `_` being used for math subscripts

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for explaining what actually happened. I think I'll either live with the (to me) sometimes inferior characters of Helvetica or with the composed umlauts. Patching every single character I don't like... twice... absolutely isn't something I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with T1 you get the underscore from the font as chosen by the font designer with OT1 you get the default which is a drawn rule

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textunderscore}{\leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule\@width.3em}}
```

so you could  define `\_` with

```
\renewcommand\_{\leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule width.3em}}
```

but some language styles my define it back, or the character may be entered as `\textbackslash` or in an environment where the usual math subscript definition is disabled and just entered as a normal character `_`  so to catch all uses is a bit tricky, and it's possibly better to just consider it a normal font letter and accept the font as a whole. The fact that `_` (and `\` ) are handled differently is really a 1970's throwback to the original 7-bit TeX encoding that only had 127 characters and could not fit these in.